# Create a Loop which answers give diff values

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

So, I am hitting this roadblock on lots of projects. I want to ask a question that has multiple answer and whichever they respond/answer with will give separate values. So, if they don't respond with one of the 3, I want the question to be asked until 1 of the 3 are given and I have they value to calculate a total meal price.

The code goes grey under the break.

I am new to programming as of like 3 weeks. So, simplicity would be much appreciated.

\\

```
while True:
    drink_type = input ('What drink did you have? Water, Soda or Lemonade?: ')
    if (drink_type == ('Soda')) : drink_price = 2.50 
    elif (drink_type == ('Water')) : drink_price = .99
    elif (drink_type == ('Lemonade')) : drink_price = 1.50
    break
    else:
    print ('Please answer Water, Soda or Lemonade.')
```

\\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to `Python` buddy, the simplest programming language in the world.

Here's your recipe of the day.

```
while True:
    drink_type = input('What drink did you have? Water, Soda or Lemonade?: ')
    if drink_type == 'Soda' : 
        drink_price = 2.50 
        break
    elif drink_type == 'Water' : 
        drink_price = .99
        break
    elif drink_type == 'Lemonade' : 
        drink_price = 1.50
        break
    else:
        print ('Please answer Water, Soda or Lemonade.')
```

Later in your learning journey you will discover `dictionnaries` which is a type of "object" in Python that lets you structure this code in a more elegant way:

```
menu = {
    "Soda": 2.50,
    "Water": .99,
    "Lemonade": 1.50
}

while True:
    drink_type = input('What drink did you have? Water, Soda or Lemonade?: ')
    if drink_type in menu:
        drink_price = menu.get(drink_type)
        break
    else:
        print('Please answer Water, Soda or Lemonade.')
```